# XML-RPC: xmlrpc_server::service: http headers already sent before response is fully generated

Tags: xml-rpc, php

I am using a web service to dispatch a zip to from one server to another server. I have been using a web service code its working fine but, sometimes web service getting error like this

> XML-RPC: xmlrpc_server::service: http headers already sent before response is fully generated

and more file requested file does not dispatching. I tried to solve this problem, but I couldn't solve it. How could achieve this? Here is my code:

```
$arg     = array(
    new xmlrpcval($result->Customer, "string"), 
    new xmlrpcval($result->JID, "string"), 
    new xmlrpcval($result->AID,"string"), 
    new xmlrpcval($fileSize,"string")
);  
$server  = new xmlrpc_client($fileName, $ip, $port);
$message = new xmlrpcmsg('sendArticleDetails', $arg);
$res     = $server->send($message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using xmlrpc from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpxmlrpc/

When the above message is thrown there could be two reasons :

a) any output has been made before the code you posted above. This can be a echo or print() message (might be inside an if statement) or an error message. (Check the display_errors settings in the php.ini )

b) an explicit call to header() in the code before

Assuming a)

Thorsten